# Can't Convert output of Camera to String

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-camera, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear All,

I have a big problem and i should solve it immediately, i want to do an image processing project, i add a camera sensor in gazebo (standalone gazebo 1.8.7 without ROS), and i can't get output of camera in my code, i can get out put of it in shell with gaztopic echo and gztopic view.
i get output of others sensor with subscribe to their topics and i do same for camera but i can't get it!!! it's my code, I'm sure that my code is correct, but i don't know how can i convert output of camera to string?!!!!!!!!!

```
subLCam  = nodeLCam->Subscribe("~/pioneer3at/leftcamera/leftlink/camera/image", `&Manage::parseLCam, this);`

void Manage::parseLCam(ConstImageStampedPtr &_img)
{
    if ( MGDebug )
        qDebug()<<"<<<MG>>> In parseLEFTCam Function.";

    QString msg(_img->ShortDebugString().c_str());

    qDebug()<<msg;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3661/can%27t-convert-output-of-camera-to-string/) by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

An example to look at is Gazebo image viewer's code, see [this function](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/gazebo/gui/viewers/ImageView.cc?at=default#cl-79)

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vahid](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/342/vahid/) on 2013-07-18**:
thank you so much dear friend, i solve it right now, it was my fault, by the way the link is very useful for me, thank you again.